# GNOME button to connect to bluetooth device autodisabling when you click to enable it

Tags: gnome, bluetooth

I'm trying to connect my **Bluetooth audio device**, but:

[image]

when I click the "disable" button to enable and connect my audio device, don't matter how many times I click, it just switch back to "disable", when it should set the button as "enabled" and connect to the device.

Any chance to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem, for some reason i uninstalled the **pulseaudio-module-bluetooth** package, so to solve this problem i just:

```
sudo apt-get install pulseaudio-module-bluetooth
```